# Laravel validation on nested model throws QueryException

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have this StoreRequest with some validation about nested model.
ex. $rules['replica.host'] = 'required';

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'host' => 'required',
        'port' => 'required',
        'user' => 'required'
    ];

    if($this->route('database')){
        $db = $this->route('database');

        $rules['name'] = 'required|unique:databases,name,'. $db->id;
        $rules['database'] = 'required|unique_with:databases,host,' . $db->id;
    }else{
        $rules['name'] = 'required|unique:databases';
        $rules['database'] = 'required|unique_with:databases,host';

        if($this->has('replica.name')){
            $rules['replica.name'] = 'required|unique:databases';
            $rules['replica.database'] = 'required|unique_with:databases,host';
            $rules['replica.host'] = 'required';
            $rules['replica.port'] = 'required';
            $rules['replica.user'] = 'required';
        }
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

i have one to one relationship on Database and Replica (Database too),
but on store i get this exception:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'replica.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `databases` where `replica`.`name` = Demo Replica)

any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because laravel uses dot `.` for nested value but I read this statement

> This issue doesn't exist anymore in laravel 5.3, 
>   we replace the dot in attribute names 
>   with -> before starting any check.

Read here : https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14211

If it is possible please replace `replica.name` by `replica_name` and same for other.  To not conflict with laravel nested check.